# How to display price in all currencies in product page?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3

How to display price in all currencies in product page?

I have added three currencies in admin panel. I check one of them as main currency. Then I added product with price.

When I scan product page I see price only in main currency. How to display price in all currencies in product page?

Ask you, answer more practic and useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCart 3.0.2.0, Default Theme

You need to edit these two files:

**1) Controller File**

```
catalog\controller\product\product.php
```

**Find**

```
$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductImages($this->request->get['product_id']);
```

**Add after it**

```
$currencies = $this->model_localisation_currency->getCurrencies();
```

**Find**

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
    $data['price'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
} else {
    $data['price'] = false;
}
```

**Change it to**

```
$data['price'] = array();
if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
    foreach ($currencies as $currency) {
        if ($currency['status']) {
            $data['price'][] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $currency['code']);
        }
    }
}
```

**2) View File**

```
catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\product.twig
```

**Find**

```
<h2>{{ price }}</h2>
```

**Change it to**

```
{% for currency_price in price %}
    <h2>{{ currency_price }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Then clear all caches (ocmod cache, twig cache, vqmod cache).

Comment: You are cool! Thank you, give me some information how to create module in Open Cart 3 with administrative part

Comment: You are welcome.
Look at an existing module, like latest module. Then create your own module.